# Nativewind reuseable component library in multiple projects

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

I would like to create a repo for a Library for UI Components thats reusable in multiple react native projects. I want to use NativeWind (tailwind for react native)

Can anyone give me any tips on how I would go about doing this? I have tried setting up a library with nativewind installed.
But when I create a component styled using nativewind, then try to run an example of using said component it doesn't show any of the styling.

I used react-native-builder-bob for boilerplate library.